# Issue with importing package

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I have issue with importing this package of Hibenate `MySQL5Dialect`  i got this error :

```
The import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect cannot be resolved
```

But in my Maven dependencies i have it already imported like it show the picture bellow :

[image]

All the others imports work fine except for this one.

Comment: Do `mvn clean compile` from your terminal to determine if it's just an IDE problem. If it works from the terminal it means you need to clean up/refresh/rebuild your workspace.

Comment: go to project --> clean, it might work